# Resource View in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I wrote a program and compiled it successfully, checked the exe file also. When i restarted visual studio; and wanted to open output file from resource view in visual studio; it gave an error  "opened in another editor" . there is no such editor. i restarted my laptop too but it doesnt work –   "OPENED IN ANOTHER EDITOR" error is under the resource view in Visual Studio. Instead of the .rc files under resource view, that error is appearing under resource view tab. I have closed all the windows also.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have the .rc or Resource.h file opened in text mode in another tab. Close all source windows and try again.

Comment: Or just click Yes!  Doesn't sound like his problem though.

Comment: @HansPassant, since the problem persists when rebooting the laptop I concluded that the file was reopened as the project was loaded.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that in your answer.  You post very good answers but I don't often get them at first.

Comment: @HansPassant, you didn't miss anything, I didn't explain my reasoning in the answer. I try to keep my answers short and easily understandable, and sometimes I go a little too far. Thanks for the compliment though.

Comment: I can't help having to mention that you are doing it wrong.  I read and vote for a lot more of your answers than a guy called "Nabeel" ever did.  Your audience is the SO community.  Well, me anyway, I'm sure there are others.  Please don't dumb down your answers because you assume that some random SO user from Asia needs to understand it first.  I like to know what you know, that's why I read your answers.  And I can actually vote :)

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm not "dumbing down" my answers, rather I'm trying to make my answers as simple as possible but not simpler. I want people to see the answer and realize "yeah, that's right" without spending a lot of time trying to read through all the intricacies. Jeff Atwood put it best: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html

Comment: Actually; "OPENED IN ANOTHER EDITOR" error is under the resource view in Visual Studio. Instead of the .rc files under resource view, that error is appearing under resource view tab. I have closed all the windows also.

Answer (score 0):

In my case delete .suo file was the solution